# Converting a Powershell ADUC query to VBS

Tags: powershell, vbscript, converters

So, I have a Powershell script that I use to see if usernames in an array are Smartcard Enabled. A lot of the scripts that are used to automate my company use VBS. Unfortunately my VBS is VERY rusty and I need to convert this powershell into VBS so my lead programmer can use it in a larger script. The script is below. I am leaving out the ADUC Hierarchy for my company's safety. It will be written in the code as "OU=,DC=" Thanks for the assist.

```
$Array="C:\UserNames.csv"

ForEach($Name in $Array)
{
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=,DC=" -Filter * -Properties * | Where {$_.CN -like "*$Name*"} | Where {$_.SmartcardLogonRequired -eg %False} | Select SamAccountName,GivenName,Surname,SmartcardLogonRequired
}
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure why the "lead programmer" is in that position if they want modern PowerShell converting to VBScript! Whatever VBScript replaces that PowerShell is going to be at least x10 bigger especially for AD related things.

Comment: He built this network 20 years ago and is set in his ways. He likes my ideas but is too busy with other projects to do this. Worse comes to worse I'll have to build his processes into powershell and hope he uses it.

Comment: You would probably be better off having the VBScript call the PowerShell and get the results that way, at least it introduces a bit of modularity.

Comment: I'd recommend sticking with PowerShell, as the language is superior to VBScript in practically every respect. However, if for some reason you must use VBScript you may find [this](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/adquery.shtml) helpful (disclosure: I'm the author).

Comment: I was hoping to find a VBS/Powershell Wizard but I've already started re-writing his script. I knew that this would be a colossal headache but I was still hopeful. I'm going to leave this open in case someone wants the challenge but I'm not that worried about it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out he didn't actually want this translated. He needed the UserAccountControl Code for SMARTCARD_REQUIRED (262144). Well, I can scrap the last 3 days of work. Thanks for the comments.